# array/object to string conversion in laravel 6 query builder

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, object, laravel-6

```
"userS": {
   "email": "jack123@test.com",
    "name": "jack"
}
```

Above is array of object in my laravel 6. it is stored in `session array`

i want to use email so i am doing this

```
$sessionUser=Session::get('userS');
$sessionEmail=$sessionUser['email'];
```

it gives me email properly in string.

so i am finding the user ID in `user table` who have this `email`

**following query gives `uid` in array/object fromat**

```
$uid=customerModel::where('email',$sessionEmail)->pluck('uid');
```

or

```
$uid=DB::select('select uid from user where email=:Email',['Email'=>$sessionEmail]);
```

but it gives me `[1]` or `[{"uid":1}]`

**(here 1 is uid which i want to use but it is in array format)**

when i insert all records then it gives me following error

Incorrect integer value: '[1]' for column `ecart`.`tblorder`.`uid` at row 1 (SQL: insert into `tblorder` (`uid`, `pid`, `quantity`, `customer_name`, `customer_email`, `customer_mobile`, `pincode`, `address`, `date`) values ([1], 2, 2, john, john@test.com, 7458965874, 123456, testXYZ, 2020-06-29 13:01:40))

**i want `simple uid` not in array or object fromat**

my sql query should be like

```
SQL: insert into `tblorder` (`uid`, `pid`, `quantity`, `customer_name`, `customer_email`, `customer_mobile`, `pincode`, `address`, `date`) values (1, 2, 2, john, john@test.com, 7458965874, 123456, testXYZ, 2020-06-29 13:01:40)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`value()`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_value) function to get a single value from the first record of the result set from the database:

```
$uid = customerModel::where('email', $sessionEmail)->value('uid');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
$uid=customerModel::select('uid')->where('email',$sessionEmail)->first()->uid;
```